# Do NOT reuse query process in LINQPad

Tags: linqpad

I have "Run each query in its own process" option turned on (default value), but it seems that the process is being reused between query runs (LINQPad.UserQuery.exe keeps running).

Is there a way to avoid this reuse? I need a fresh process every time (due to JVM usage).

Obvious way is

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

but it results in unpleasant "Query ended unexpectedly" message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Util.NewProcess = true`:

```
Util.NewProcess = true;
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.Dump();
```

Also you can try option from menu: 'Query' -> 'Cancel All Threads and Reset' (also available via shortcut `Shift+Control+F5`)

Answer (score 7):

The option "Run each query in its own process" instructs LINQPad to use process isolation rather than AppDomain isolation. It will still re-use the process if you re-run the same query.

The option you want is "Always use fresh application domains". Set this to true, and you'll get a fresh process/AppDomain with each execution. Or, as the Guru suggested, set `Util.NewProcess` in your query. This forces the next execution to use a fresh process/domain.

Comment: Thank you, Joe! Since I'm creating a NuGet package with samples for our framework, Util.NewProcess seems to be the best way, so the users won't have to change their settings.